# @font-face error in CSS3

Tags: css, font-face

When I attempt to add the code shown below to my CSS3 stylesheet, I get errors
saying that 'format('xxxx')' is not a valid value for the src property. If I remove the space before "format" the error goes away but I don't know if the code is being processed.

I am getting burned out. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you,

Yuri

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'arialregular';
    src: url('arial-webfont.eot');
    src: url('arial-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('arial-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('arial-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('arial-webfont.svg#arialregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Where is the error appearing? That font-face code looks like it should work, I just copied and pasted it into a new file with no errors. Though I don't have arialregular on my desktop

Comment: Do you need to list `local()` first in your `src` before all the `url()`s?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using this below, replace the paths

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoLight';
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Lig-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Lato-Lig-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/Lato-Lig-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/Lato-Lig-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/Lato-Lig-webfont.svg#LatoLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
local('arialregular')
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'arialregular';
    src: url('arial-webfont.eot');
    src: local('arialregular'),
         url('arial-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('arial-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('arial-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('arial-webfont.svg#arialregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Also, this looks like a nice guide for [`@font-face`](http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/10/30/how-to-use-css-font-face/).